# Prove parameter independence of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, definite-integrals, entropy

In working out certain particle-to-particle collisions and entropy, I did come up with a problem. Hence, I am going to ask it here. There are similar calculations that enter the picture in dealing with Feynman integrals. So, other people may find this interesting as well.

> **QUESTION.** Is the following integral independent of $0<z<1$?
> $$\int_0^1\frac{\log\vert z-t\vert}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt.$$

Comment: A similar integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407304/evaluating-int-01-frac-ln-x-ln-1-x-sqrtx-sqrt1-x-dx) (containing an extra factor of $\ln t$)

Comment: Thank you. What complicates things is the absolute value around $z$, which forces some splitting the integral $0<x<z$ and $z<x<1$, unlike the ones in your link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denoting $z=\sin^2 a;\,a\in[0;\frac\pi2]$
$$I(z)=\int_0^1\frac{\log\vert z-t\vert}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt\overset{x=\sqrt t}{=}2\int_0^1\frac{\ln|z-x^2|}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
$$\overset{x=\sin\phi}{=}2\int_0^\frac\pi2\ln|\sin^2a-\sin^2\phi|d\phi=\frac14\int_0^{4\pi}\ln|\sin^2a-\sin^2\phi|d\phi$$
$$=\frac14\int_0^{4\pi}\left(\ln\Big|2\sin\frac{\phi-a}2\,\cos\frac{\phi+a}2\Big|+\ln\Big|2\sin\frac{\phi+a}2\,\cos\frac{\phi-a}2\Big|\right)d\phi$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\Big(2\ln 2+\ln|\sin(\phi-a)|+\ln|\sin(\phi+a)|+\ln|\cos(\phi-a)|+\ln|\cos(\phi+a)|\Big)d\phi$$
We see that $a$ (or, initially $z$) does not contribute due to periodicity of the functions of the integrand.

Taking into consideration that $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac\pi2\ln(\cos\phi)d\phi=\int_0^\frac\pi2\ln(\sin\phi)d\phi=-\,\frac\pi 2\ln2$
$$I(z)=2\pi\ln2+\frac12\cdot4\cdot4\int_0^\frac\pi2\ln(\cos\phi)d\phi=-2\pi\ln2$$

Comment: Cool! Thank you.